# I can't get Visual Studio 2015 to change the program icon for new build's

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm having this weird issue with Visual Studio 2015, and I'm not sure if it's my fault or if it's a glitch. I originally built this program using an icon that was dominantly black. I've since noticed that the black is way too hard to see on the Windows task bar, and even on the desktop. I updated the logo to be dominantly white with a black border to make it pop. However, when I update the .ico file in the project properties (not form properties), and rebuild the executable, it still uses the old black logo.

Here's where it gets funny. I deleted any instance of this old logo that I had (even in the project resources folder), and it still does it. It's obviously caching this file somewhere, but I don't know where, and this is really starting to bug me. If someone could help me with this or has any idea's, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rebuild the Windows IconCache.

> go to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local folder and delete the hidden
>   IconCache.db file. Reboot.

Source: [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows)

What version of Windows do you use?

You could also try deleting the *iconcache* files in `"%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\"`

Source: [Ten Forums](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I'll try this when I get off work, it looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry dude, I completely forgot to reply. It worked perfect thank you! It also fixed some other icon issues I was having. I'll definitely keep this in my toolbox for the next time I have a similar issue.